# How to Add Alexa Certificate to Mediawiki Header?

Tags: mediawiki, alexa-internet

I would like to add Alexa Certificate to Mediawiki, put i can't find the header file to include the code (`<script></script>`) in there.

1. Which file should i put for all Pages to be certified and recognize
   by Alexa?
2. Is there a way to put the code in there without damaging any Page?

Answer (score 1):

Add in `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgHooks["ParserFirstCallInit"][] = "fnAlexaCertificate";
function fnAlexaCertificate() {

  global $wgOut;

  $wgOut->addHeadItem("AlexaCertificate", '<meta name="" content="">');

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgHooks["ParserFirstCallInit"][] = function () use ($wgOut) {
    $wgOut->addHeadItem("AlexaCertificate", '<meta name="" content="">');
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add any sitewide JavaScript to your wiki is to login as an Administrator of your wiki.  Then add the necessary Javascript to **MediaWiki:Common.js** and **MediaWiki:Mobile.js** See the manual at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

For everyone that is trying to solve this problem, you simply locate your Skin file and you embedded the code in the .php file of your skin.

My Location was:

```
/skins/Vector.php
```

You can paste the code within one of the  tags.

Hope it help anyone trying to use Alexa. :)

Comment: You don't really want to make custom modifications to skins. You'll lose them, or have to re-implement them on update.